# PeerJs Issue On locahost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to implement the zoom clone with WebRTC using peerjs, the problem is `myPeer.on("call", (call) => {` its never calling, this same code is executing on the locahost for the others who made the tutorial on zoom clone, I am not sure where is the problem with my code,

Its working on **heroku** though its not working on localhost, so where is the problem with my localhost setup, why i am not getting the other users who joined the room on ***localhost***, I am not understanding.

**script.js**

```js
  
const socket = io("/");
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: "/peerjs",
  host: "/",
  port: "3030",
});
let myVideoStream;
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;
const peers = {};
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

    // Never Called this myPeer.on call
    myPeer.on("call", (call) => {
      call.answer(stream);
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      });
    });

    socket.on("user-connected", (userId) => {
      console.log("User Connected", userId);
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
    });
    // input value
    let text = $("input");
    // when press enter send message
    $("html").keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13 && text.val().length !== 0) {
        socket.emit("message", text.val());
        text.val("");
      }
    });
    socket.on("createMessage", (message) => {
      $("ul").append(`<li class="message"><b>user</b><br/>${message}</li>`);
      scrollToBottom();
    });
  });

socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId) => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close();
});

myPeer.on("open", (id) => {
  socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
});

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
  });
  call.on("close", () => {
    video.remove();
  });

  peers[userId] = call;
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    video.play();
  });
  videoGrid.append(video);
}

const scrollToBottom = () => {
  var d = $(".main__chat_window");
  d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight"));
};

const muteUnmute = () => {
  const enabled = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setUnmuteButton();
  } else {
    setMuteButton();
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
};

const playStop = () => {
  console.log("object");
  let enabled = myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setPlayVideo();
  } else {
    setStopVideo();
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
};

const setMuteButton = () => {
  const html = `
    <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
    <span>Mute</span>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".main__mute_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const setUnmuteButton = () => {
  const html = `
    <i class="unmute fas fa-microphone-slash"></i>
    <span>Unmute</span>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".main__mute_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const setStopVideo = () => {
  const html = `
    <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    <span>Stop Video</span>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".main__video_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const setPlayVideo = () => {
  const html = `
  <i class="stop fas fa-video-slash"></i>
    <span>Play Video</span>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".main__video_button").innerHTML = html;
};
```

**server.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// const cors = require('cors')
// app.use(cors())
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require("peer");
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  debug: true,
});
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require("uuid");

app.use("/peerjs", peerServer);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`);
});

app.get("/:room", (req, res) => {
  res.render("room", { roomId: req.params.room });
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit("user-connected", userId);
    // messages
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      //send message to the same room
      io.to(roomId).emit("createMessage", message);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit("user-disconnected", userId);
    });
  });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3030);
```

Answer (score 2):

the function `connectToNewUser` get executed before the `myPeer.on('call')`

try modifying the function as

```
socket.on("user-connected", (userId) => {
   console.log("User Connected", userId);
   //connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
   setTimeout(connectToNewUser,1000,userId,stream)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it seemed to be a race condition with `socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);`.

The server will emit `socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit("user-connected", userId);` which will trigger the function that calls the peer in `connectToNewUser` before the user has finished the navigator promise.

I solved my issue by making sure the navigator promise has finished before firing `socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);`.